# In c# array of strings, the individual elements of array are reference type or value type?

Tags: c#, string

Since in any array , array itself is a reference type and individual elements of array are value type ... is this the case with array of strings too?

Comment: "and individual elements of array are value type" - is a fallacy; the elements of an `int[]` are value-types (`int`), but the elements of a `string[]` are reference-types (`string`)

Answer (score 3):

The items in an array are values, but they can be either a value type or a reference type.

For an array of value types, the value itself is stored in the array.

For an array of reference types, the references to the objects are stored in the array.

So, an array of strings is actually an array of string references.

Answer (score 2):

`System.String` is a reference type.

Comment: the individual elements in array ... for e.g in 
string [] str={"the","hero"} 
the and hero are reference or value types?

Comment: @SanaZehra, they are whatever the underlying type of the element is.  In an array of `int`, the element type is a value type.  In an array of, say `string`, they are reference types.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are [not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) value types.  And there's no reason their contents should be a value type, unless of course, they are in fact, value types. (e.g. `int`).

```
int[] intArray;  // intArray is a reference type.  It holds ints, a value type
string[] stringArray; // stringArray is a reference type.  It holds strings, a reference type
```

**EDIT**: Specific quote from referenced page about the array type:

> Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type
>   Array. Since this type implements IEnumerable and IEnumerable, you
>   can use foreach iteration on all arrays in C#.

Comment: so the array of objects basically ... holds objects (references to the objects) hence the array of objects and the contents of such an array are both reference types right??? ...

Comment: @SanaZehra, the array is a reference type, period.  That doesn't change.  What *does* change is whether the element-type (what the array contains) is a reference-type or a value-type.  That is *entirely* dependant on the type in question.  Hence, the elements of an `int` array are value-types, whilst the elements of a `string` array are reference types.

Answer (score 0):

> individual elements of array are value type

Wrong. An array's underlying element type can either be of value or of reference.

Answer (score 0):

[string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)   - It is reference type in case of array also.
The string type represents a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters. string is an alias for [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) in the .NET Framework.

The [] operator can be used for readonly access to individual characters of a string:

```
string str = "test";
char x = str[2];  // x = 's';
```

String literals are of type string and can be written in two forms, quoted and @-quoted. Quoted string literals are enclosed in double quotation marks (")

check the msdn documentation link for detailed information about this.